# Facebook Like Button HTML5 code Errors

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm currently having trouble using facebook like button in html5 version, it seems that everytime the visitor of my wordpress blog liked a blog post, it's not working. It will work for a while but when you refresh it, it goes back to active button which is very strange since the user already liked the blog post.

I also encountered that when i liked my own blog post, it fetched the wrong details. example, i liked the blog post #1 but when i check my facebook, it the fetched image is wrong, the description and title is also wrong.

what is the proper way to add a facebook like button in wordpress blog?

any help?

Comment: have you tried to use the linter to debug it ?
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

do you have the correct opengraph tags implemented.
For a like button you should have tags like title, image, link and description.

Comment: thank you, i already tried the linter but i still encoutered the non working facebook like button. thank you for your help, I might try the suggestion below.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same error before. I already tried the linter to debug it but it really doesn't work. Anyway, my simple solution to that is I changed my facebook like code to **Iframe version** (since html5 give me crap, there's no harm if I use iframe lol). I don't encountered any errors with that. It works perfectly.

about your question on [how to add facebook like in your index file or multiple blog posts in wordpress](http://www.bendaggers.com/how-to-add-facebook-like-twitter-tweet-google-plus-one-and-pinterest-pin-it-button-in-your-index-file-multiple-blog-posts-in-wordpress/), the link (guide on how to...) might help you. I used that before. It also discusses about twitter tweet, google plus and pinterest pin it button's wordpress implementation.

have a good day!